# SQL: Missing columns after INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

Basically I have two old tables, and new one which combines parts of both by matching ID as referance.

One old table is named "*items_table*" and contains the following columns: 
"Material" (which I use as ID to navigate to the items), "Condition", "Quantity", "Desc" (and a bunch of other irrelevant columns for now which I don't use)

Second old table is named "*price_table*" and contains: "ItemNum", "itemtype", "_subtype", "FullPrice" (and more columns which I don't want to include in my new table)

And a third new temporary table which is named "*Items4sale*" and should contain the following columns (values are inserted by query from the old tables): "ID", "_Type", "Subtype", "Condition", "Desc", "Quantity", "FullPrice", "Price" (this is a new calculated value), "PotentiaPrice" (this is a new calculated value)

Here's the code:

```
if object_id('Items4sale') is not null  /* <--- creating the new table */
drop table Items4sale;
create table Items4sale (
ID int,
_Type NVARCHAR(100),
Subtype NVARCHAR(100),
Condition INT,
Descr NVARCHAR(100),
Quantity INT,
FullPrice float, /* <--- I actually want to limit the display for prices, for example to "3299.33" instead of "3299.332120" */
Price float, 
PotentialPrice float
)

INSERT INTO Items4sale (ID, _Type, Subtype, FullPrice) /* Inserting here columns from "price_table" */
SELECT [ItemNum], [itemtype], [_subtype], [FullPrice]
FROM price_table WHERE [ItemNum] in (SELECT [Material] from items_table)  /* Same ID of the item should match to one in the items_table */
    INSERT INTO Items4sale (ID, Condition, Quantity, Descr) /* Inserting here columns from "items_table" */
SELECT [Material] (same for ID), [site_loc], [limit], [descriptions]
FROM items_table WHERE cast([site_loc] as CHAR(50)) like '%8';  /* Use only if "site_loc" column (to insert in "Condition" in the new table) ends with "8" ("5338" for example is OK and should be included) */

UPDATE Items4sale set Price=FullPrice*0.05
UPDATE items4sale set PotentialPrice=Price*Quantity

SELECT * FROM Items4sale
```

This is what I get as a result:

```
ID  |  _Type  |  Subtype | Condition  |  Descr  | Quantity | FullPrice | Price | PotentialPrice
189 |  Plastic | Toy     | NULL       | NULL    | NULL     | 8         | 0.4   | NULL
                     .........
```

Notice how "Condition", "Descr", "Quantity, and "PotentialPrice" come up as NULL. Those matching columns (as in the INSERT in the code above) are not null in the "items_table" where "ID" is "189".

This is the result that I wanted: (example)

> ```
> ID  |  _Type  |  Subtype | Condition              |  Descr           | Quantity | FullPrice | Price | PotentialPrice
> 189 |  Plastic | Toy     | 3998 *(ends with '8')* | A plastic toy    | 4        | 8         | 0.4   | 1.6
>                      .........
> ```

How can I fix this?

Also, second part of my question - here's a query I ran to test for bugs, (in addition to the code above):

```
SELECT * FROM Items4sale WHERE ID = 189;
SELECT * FROM items_table WHERE [Material] = 189;
```

The above is to see if there are any missing duplicated IDs in my first query. 
Turns out that in "items_table" there is more than one "189" as "Material" (ID of the item)
So from the second "SELECT" in the code above I get several rows with "189" as Material (ID) because there's actually more than one - I didn't take into account a column which is named "Location" (NVARCHAR(100)) in this table. I believe this is a bit more advanced: In case there's more than one row which has the ID in "items_table", then don't combine them to one row in "Items4sale" (the combined new table), but instead create them as ID = "189", "(1)189", "(2)189" (just like windows does when you try to create the same file/folder twice) yet their "Condition" (items_table.[site_loc]) in this case doesn't end with '8'. I still want to list them and apply their price and etc from "price_table".

This is important as the items might be the same (have the same barcode/ID), but have different "Location" and thus probably different "Quantity" aswell.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt fails because, basically, you are running 2 insert statements while you want just one record being generated.

While it should be possible to first `insert` with the columns from one table, then `update` with columns from the other one, it is simpler to perform the whole operation at once with an `insert ... select` query:

```
insert into items4sale
    (ID, _Type, Subtype, FullPrice, Condition, Quantity, Descr, Price, PotentialPrice)
select
    p.ItemNum, 
    p.ItemType, 
    p.Subtype, 
    p.FullPrice,
    i.site_loc,
    i.limit,
    i.descriptions,
    p.FullPrice * 0.05,
    p.FullPrice * 0.05 * i.limit
from items i
inner join prices p on p.ItemNum = i.Material
```

Unrelated note: from my understanding of your use case (you want to display derived information), this query would better fit in a view; this gives you an always-up-to-date perspective on your joined data '(on the other hand, a table requires manual updating, which can get tedious).

Comment: Hi, your code works OK, however for some reason “site_loc” (within the new table) returns NULL...

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps because that column **doesn't exist** in your table or in your code